What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a Dirichlet series to admit analytic continuation?
Let $A = \{a(n)\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. By normalizing, we may as well assume that $|a(n)| \leq 1$ for all $n \geq 1$. Under this assumption, the Dirichlet series
$\displaystyle D_A(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$
converges absolutely on the half-plane $\mathbb{H}_{>1} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 1\}$.
What is the most general statement, in terms of conditions on the sequence $A$, which guarantees that $D_A(s)$ can be analytically continued to give a meromorphic function on the whole complex plane?
Certain examples show that conditions might be quite subtle. For example, if
$\displaystyle a(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n \text{ is prime} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$
then $D_A(s)$ cannot be analytically continued.

I don't think there is a general condition per se. Let $B(x)=\sum_{n \leq x} a_n$. Then the analytic continuability of $D_{A}(s)$ is entirely determined by the asymptotic behaviour of $B(x)$. Note that $D_{A}(s) = s\int_{1}^{\infty} B(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$ if $\Re(s)$ is large enough. Then $D_{A}(s)$ has an analytic continuation to $\Re(s)>\alpha$ iff $B(x) \ll x^{\alpha}$. In particular, if $B(x)$ is of constant sign for $x \geq x_0$, then $D_{A}(s)$ has an analytic continuation to the right side of its abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c$, but not at $s=\sigma_c$.
